# Getting Error "k = 0 must be at least 1" when i give k a value in kNN algorithm (R)

Tags: r, knn

When ever I put this line of code:

```
> m1 <- knn( train = trainSetNorm[,c(1:41)], test = testSetNorm[,c(1:41)], 
cl = trainSetNorm[,c(42)], k = 703)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in knn(train = trainSetNorm[, c(1:41)], test = testSetNorm[, c(1:41)],: 
k = 0 must be at least 1
```

I used the KDD Cup 99 corrected as the corrected 10 percent data set. The 10 percent is used and the training data and the corrected is used as the test data.  Here's the exact code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/BIGLOU")
```

Load Data Set

```
testSet <- read.delim('corrected', sep = ',', header = FALSE)
colnames(testSet) <- c("duration", "protocol_type", "service", "flag", 
"src_bytes", "dst_bytes", "land", 
                    "wrong_fragment", "urgent", "hot", "num_failed_logins", 
"logged_in", "num_compromised",
                    "root_shell", "su_attempted", "num_root", 
"num_file_creations", "num_shells", 
                    "num_access_files", "num_outbound_cmds", 
"is_host_login","is_guest_login", "count", "srv_count", 
                    "serror_rate", "srv_serror_rate", "rerror_rate", 
"srv_rerror_rate", "same_srv_rate", "diff_srv_rate",
                    "srv_diff_host_rate", "dst_host_count", 
"dst_host_srv_count", "dst_host_same_srv_rate", 
                    "dst_host_diff_srv_rate", "dst_host_same_src_port_rate", 
"dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate",
                    "dst_host_serror_rate", "dst_host_srv_serror_rate", 
"dst_host_rerror_rate", "dst_host_srv_rerror_rate",
                    "connection_type")

trainSet <- read.delim('kddcup.data_10_percent_corrected', sep = ',', header = FALSE)
colnames(trainSet) <- c("duration", "protocol_type", "service", "flag", "src_bytes", "dst_bytes", "land", 
                    "wrong_fragment", "urgent", "hot", "num_failed_logins", 
"logged_in", "num_compromised",
                    "root_shell", "su_attempted", "num_root", 
"num_file_creations", "num_shells", 
                    "num_access_files", "num_outbound_cmds", 
"is_host_login","is_guest_login", "count", "srv_count", 
                    "serror_rate", "srv_serror_rate", "rerror_rate", 
"srv_rerror_rate", "same_srv_rate", "diff_srv_rate",
                    "srv_diff_host_rate", "dst_host_count", 
"dst_host_srv_count", "dst_host_same_srv_rate", 
                    "dst_host_diff_srv_rate", "dst_host_same_src_port_rate", 
"dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate",
                    "dst_host_serror_rate", "dst_host_srv_serror_rate", 
"dst_host_rerror_rate", "dst_host_srv_rerror_rate",
                    "connection_type")
```

Change Catagorical Values to Numerical Values.

```
testSet[,c(2)] <- as.integer(testSet[,c(2)])
testSet[,c(3)] <- as.integer(testSet[,c(3)])
testSet[,c(4)] <- as.integer(testSet[,c(4)])
testSet[,c(7)] <- as.integer(testSet[,c(7)])
testSet[,c(12)] <- as.integer(testSet[,c(12)])
testSet[,c(21)] <- as.integer(testSet[,c(21)])
testSet[,c(22)] <- as.integer(testSet[,c(22)])

trainSet[,c(2)] <- as.integer(trainSet[,c(2)])
trainSet[,c(3)] <- as.integer(trainSet[,c(3)])
trainSet[,c(4)] <- as.integer(trainSet[,c(4)])
trainSet[,c(7)] <- as.integer(trainSet[,c(7)])
trainSet[,c(12)] <- as.integer(trainSet[,c(12)])
trainSet[,c(21)] <- as.integer(trainSet[,c(21)])
trainSet[,c(22)] <- as.integer(trainSet[,c(22)])
```

Randomize the Data Set

```
set.seed(60223)
rand <-runif(nrow(testSet))
testSet <- testSet[order(rand),]
set.seed(12558)
rand <-runif(nrow(trainSet))
trainSet <- trainSet[order(rand),]
```

Normalize the input data

```
normalize <- function(x) {return( abs((x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))))}
testSetNorm <- as.data.frame(lapply(testSet[,c(1:41)],normalize))
trainSetNorm <- as.data.frame(lapply(trainSet[,c(1:41)],normalize))

testSetNorm <-cbind(testSetNorm, testSet[,c(42)])
colnames(testSet)[42] <- "connection_type"
trainSetNorm <-cbind(trainSetNorm, trainSet[,c(42)])
colnames(trainSet)[42] <- "connection_type"
```

Remove any missing data points

```
trainSetNorm <- trainSetNorm[complete.cases(trainSetNorm),]
testSetNorm <- testSetNorm[complete.cases(testSetNorm),]


require(class)
m1 <- knn( train = trainSetNorm[,c(1:41)], test = testSetNorm[,c(1:41)], cl = trainSetNorm[,c(42)], k = 703)
```

Comment: Can you share a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: There is more than one implementation of knn.  Which package are you using?

Comment: Im using the knn algorithm from the "class" package